# Turn off Intel RST for Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, intel-rst, intel

I was trying to install ubuntu 20.04 version, but I was warned to turn off RST. I've looked for a lot of solutions, and they said I should change the SATA settings in BIOS setup.
But there is no SATA-related modification in BIOS setup on my desktop. In this case, what should be done to turn off RST?

Comment: What is your motherboard make and model?   If Intel RST is there, there would be an option in BIOS to disable it.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the warning or error message? My guess the warning message is worded in such a way, simply suggests turning of Intel RST, if it’s turned on.

Comment: Welcome to SU. As you've noticed the question is a bit  difficult to answer at the moment. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771513/edit) it to add the requested info. If you're not able to provide a screenshot, try to take a good quality photo, upload it to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) or similar service and add the link. For the future, it's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/help) and check the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) in a new site. You'll find for example advice on [how to formulate the question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).